# How do I selectively remove objects from a sequence in parallel?

Tags: c++, c++11

Well the title pretty well sums it up. I got to this ugly place by profiling. I usually use Open MP 2.0 but as far as I can tell there's no easy way of doing it with OMP2.0. I'm using Concurrency::parallel_for instead, but I can't seem to get it to work.

So I have a list of Obj objects called *unallocated*, which I want to remove if they meet a certain criterion. Since I can't remove them within the loop itself in parallel, I am instead trying to store iterators to the corresponding locations in *unallocated* in another sequence called *preallocated*, which I will use to call the list::erase() function later in a serial loop.

Here is what I have so far:

```
// (std::list<Obj> unallocated is already created and full of Obj objects)

typedef std::list<Obj>::iterator ItUnallocated;

concurrency::concurrent_vector<ItUnallocated> preallocated;

// We can now do a parallelised search through all remaining elments of unallocated to 
//check if the cell pointer collides with any other unallocated cells, which will be added to
// the preallocated sequence.
concurrency::parallel_for
    (
    unallocated.begin(),
    unallocated.end(), 
    [&](ItUnallocated const it) 
    {
        if (Criterion(*it)) // check if the criterion is met
        {
            // criterion is met! Add the iterator
            preallocated.push_back(it);
        }
    }
);
// run through each element of *preallocated* in serial and call unallocated.erase() for each of the elements.
```

Compiling this, I get the following error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\ppl.h(3447): error C2440: '' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'

What am I doing wrong here (other than the fact that I've created an abomination). Productive criticism please; I know it's horrible, a better solution will be gladly considered!

NOTE: I am using a list because it vectors were too slow in the last part (running through preallocated and remove the iterator locations).

Comment: Is there some spectacularly great reason you *need* to use a `list` here? If you can use a vector, it'll probably give faster serial code, *and* be a lot easier to parallelize (break the input into N chunks to work on in N threads, producing N outputs that you then merge).

Comment: The `parallel_for` will iterate as the `std::for_each algorithm`, meaning the argument passed to your operator is a reference to the object contained by the container, here, an `Obj&`, not an `ItUnallocated`. So your lambda function specification do not match the algorithm. Hence the error.

Comment: @lip for_each would iterate through every element of index_type, and would take a lambda parameter which accepts input_type. I'm my case ItUnallocated is the index type, so why doesn't it work?

Comment: @JerryCoffin It would be easier to paralellise but slower. Erasing the elements that are selected from unallocated was a serious bottleneck. I don't want to parallelise the code if it's going to be 5 times slower, then even with 8 cores I'm unlikely to see a gain.

Comment: Make your lambda take (const Obj& obj) instead of ItUnallocated as @lip mentioned and your code will compile.

Comment: @Jagannath why? This is a for loop, not for_each... How would you use parallel_for to loop through a series of integers if it would always try to dereference index_type?

Comment: Why not run `std::remove_if` in parallel on separate segments of the sequence, then consolidate removed ranges?

Comment: Sorry @ausairman, i'm not familiar with Microsoft parallel library. [Check the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470426.aspx) , parallel_for accepts only an **integral** *index_type*, hence the error. Iterators are not integrals, hence the error. If I had to code this, I would use std::remove_if on a concurrent container, eg. Intel TBB [concurrent_queue](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/tbb_sa/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_queue_cls.htm)

Comment: @lip Thanks! I didn't see that. I'll look into the remove_if option, although I'm reluctant to introduce any more O(N) than I have to...

Comment: @ausairman Multiple O(n) stays O(n) that's landeau beauty ^^ More precisely, making m * O(n) iterations or a big O(n) iteration making m operations usually meet the same performance bench. The iteration itself is *very* performant. If n is under a zillion and you operation is more complicated than a constant addition, you should not be concerned by multiple iterations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parallel_for` only accepts integer types as boundaries. You can keep the idea and use a `vector` with a `parallel_for` loop on indexes:

```
typedef std::vector<Obj>::iterator ItUnallocated;
std::vector<Obj> unallocated;
concurrency::concurrent_vector<ItUnallocated> preallocated;

concurrency::parallel_for<size_t>
    (
    0,
    unallocated.size(),
    [&](size_t index)
    {
        if(Criterion(unallocated[index]))
            preallocated.push_back(unallocated.begin() + index);
    }
);
```

Also note than `concurrency`is Microsoft-only. You may want to use the very similar [Intel thread Building Blocks library](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org), which is portable.